# Как вывести данные $_POST в php

Tags: php

Отправляю аяксом POST формы

```
$('#_formOrder').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let $form = $(this);
            let $order = $form.serialize()
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "/assets/ajax.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                   "action": "order",
                    "order" : $order
                },
                success: function(data) {
                   
                },
                error: function(data) { // Данные не отправлены

                }
              });
        });
```

уходят вот так данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вывести данные order?

пробовал так,

```
$product = $_POST['order']['username'];
print_r($product);
```

но не работает

Comment: А посмотреть `$_POST`? Думаю там и ответ сразу увидите.

Comment: У вас в `$_POST['order']` строка с кучей символов, как это и видно в скриншоте. К куче символов нельзя обращаться, как к массиву по ключу. Разбейте ее на части и берите, что нужно.

Comment: `parse_str( $_POST['order'] , $data );  var_dump( $data['username'] );`

Answer (score 0):

Вы отправляете два параметра, action и order. Чтобы увидеть, что получает сервер, напишем функцию вывода этих полученных данных:

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $order = $_POST['order'];
    echo "Action: ".$action."<br>";
    echo "Order: ".$order."<br>";
?>
```

*Аргументируйте минус? Вопрос был в том, как вывести данные переданные методом POST, ответ я дал. Вопрос заключался не в том, как правильно передавать данные, а в том как их вывести..*